# Unable to access images from asset packs android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm creating a react-native app with play asset delivery. I've integrated install-time asset pack delivery as per the documentation but don't know how to access those images in my native code . Please anyone help

Comment: consider adding more detail to your question that includes what have you tried so far

Comment: I am trying to do this as well. Any luck since posting this?